# Adding imageview in the uiscrollview with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have 1 scrollview and many imageview (1 or 2, it will vary). I am still learning autolayout. I plan to add image view to scrollview starting from right side of content in scroll view.

[image]

Problem is

1. How can I relate my imageview to the right side content of the scrollview? (not right side of scrollview).
2. Is `initWithFrame` okay to use in autolayout?
3. Below is my draft idea of how I plan to implement. Is there any good/better way to do? May I know how to do?

   ```
   for(int item = 0; item < self.allData.count; item++)
   {
       UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.svAttractions.contentSize.width - width, 0, width, height)];

       if(item == 0)
       {
           //this is first item and I will add constraint to the right side of my image view to ride side content view of scrollview
           NSLayoutConstraint *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:img attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:?? attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
       }       

       if(item == self.allData.count - 1)
       {
           //this is last item and i will add constraint to the left side of image view to left side of content view of scrollview            
       }
       else
       {
           //this is not last item yet and i will add constrait to current right side image view to previous left side image view           
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You'd probably be better going with a sidescrolling UICollectionView since you'll have a varying number of images. It's a bit strange to 'begin' content on the right, but with a UICollectionView you could simply reverse the order of your data, and start the contentOffset at the end.